# How to use properly viewer node

Tags: node-editor

I'm having my first approach with Nodes, I don't understand how to use the viewer node, on the manual it is said that <kbd>shift</kbd> +<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> on the node and the viewer must appear, but nothing appends when I do this. And just for clarity, does LMB stands for Left Mouse Botton?

Comment: Based off the answer you accepted, it looks like you were looking for a viewer node in the *material editor*.  This requires the Node Wrangler addon, however the inspiration for this feature comes from the viewer node present by default (accessible through [ctrl]+[shift]+[LMB] as well) in the *compositor*.  Node wrangler, among other things, adds a similar feature to the material editor which is quite handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That action is dependent on having the **Node Wrangler** Add-on enabled. Go into User Preferences > Add-ons and enable it.

[image: NW]

Comment: Thank you so much, you make my day